# Currently I integrate spa (asp .net core 3.1) with IdentityServer4. Can I upgrade to asp .net core 6 without changing IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4, single-page-application, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

Currently, I have a web application (asp .net core 3.1) which integrated with IdentityServer4. Can I upgrade to asp .net core 6 without changing Identity Server 4?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer4 offers an identity service over OpenId Connect protocol. This protocol is based on Http. It does not matter what technology the client use. As Http is a standard protocol, you can consume it from any type of application (Net, Java, Javascript, Node...).

In fact, your SPA is served from an Asp Net Core 3.1 application but the identity service is consumed from the browser (js).

Comment: Thanks @Alpha75. I got first answer as identity service is independent of application. My second question is can we consume Identity service at first load of application instead of spa (angluar)?